# How to add a complete menu as an item in other menus?

Tags: routes

Let say I have 3 MENUS:

**MENU 1** with these items:

```
item menu 1 - a
item menu 1 - b
item menu 1 - c
```

**MENU 2** with these items:

```
item menu 2 - a
item menu 2 - b
item menu 2 - c
```

**MENU 3** with these items:

```
item menu 3 - a
item menu 3 - b
item menu 3 - c
```

I need to add **MENU 1** as a clild in **MENU 2** and **MENU 3** to get this:

**MENU 2** with these items:

```
item menu 2 - a
item menu 2 - b
--item menu 1 - a
--item menu 1 - b
--item menu 1 - c
item menu 2 - c
```

**MENU 3** with these items:

```
item menu 3 - a
item menu 3 - b
--item menu 1 - a
--item menu 1 - b
--item menu 1 - c
item menu 3 - c
```

Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a sandbox project for combining menus: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/klickreflex/1989788

[Someone with a similar issue found code that was of value.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2390751#comment-9424879)

The poster also suggests [Advanced Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_menu) which has some merging capabilities.

Comment: I think that Advanced Menu would do the job. I'll try.